# Share image over Bluetooth in android

Tags: android

Please help me for share the image over Bluetooth in android devices that when send the image from one device Bluetooth to another device Bluetooth.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I would suggest the Bluetooth File Transfer app. https://play.google.com/store/apps/details?id=it.medieval.blueftp&feature=search_result#?t=W251bGwsMSwyLDEsIml0Lm1lZGlldmFsLmJsdWVmdHAiXQ..

Comment: thanks for reply but I want to help in source coding. so have any idea for sharing data over bluetooth please reply me..